# Is it possible to rewrite your javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, if-statement

I would like to edit my if else statement in javascript dynamically.

So after one if statement is used, it could be removed. I get this maybe isn't possible but after a search online failed, my curiosity begged me to ask.

For instance:

```
if (x > 200 && x % 25 === 0) {
  doSomething1();
} else if (x > 300 && !inRange) {
  doSomething2();
} else if (x > 400 && x % 7 === 0) {
  doSomething3();
}
```

There are eight if else statements within this loop. The loop determines which object to create. There are 2000 objects created over the course of a couple minutes. If on average we reach the fourth statement before it breaks, then there are 8,000 calculations being performed just within this one set of statements.

I want to streamline the script for speed and again, curiosity if we can actually write javascript dynamically without using separate functions etc. After an if statement fails, it is often not required anymore. The next statement could I suppose, include code to remove its predecessor dynamically. This might save 3 or 4 thousand calculations - not huge I know, but worthy of consideration given that there are lots of other things going on as well.

Is there a way to remove them dynamically or does anyone have any tricks or patterns up their sleeves?

Also, even if this is not available in js, what would this be called?

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found that you have a bottleneck?  If not, you're probably [optimizing prematurely](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Hey Josh, I am running alot of code. It is a fairly intense animation so every little bit I save makes the animation more stable in slower computers. However, I also think it would be more elegant to be able to remove these statements rather than using flags. I thought I'd throw it out there just to make sure it is not possible, because if it was, I think it would be very useful.

Comment: If you're doing animations in the browser, you're most likely better off using [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) rather than manually changing the properties of elements from JS.  The browser can optimize and hardware-accelerate CSS animations in ways that you cannot from script.

Comment: Hey Josh, I am definitely using CSS animations. But depending upon a count, I am determining whether it should fire off one object or another. I am using javascript to launch the css animations when they are supported by the browser.

Comment: The last thing you should worry about when optimizing is a few if statements... Especially if they do nothing but compare a value to a number!  You're _WAY_ overthinking this.

Comment: Hey jahroy, there are about eight if statements, and each one might say -  else if ( count < 901 && count % 25 === 0 )... not a big deal, and I'm not worried. But this set of statements is run 2000 times throughout the animation to determine which objects to create. I also really wanted to know if there was a way to rewrite javascript dynamically - especially if statements. I just wanted to throw it out at the community.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to remove them dynamically? Altering the code dynamically is unnecessary and a bag of worms that's overdoing it for this situation. You should be using a flag.

I'll answer separately for whether you're trying to skip a large group of if statements, or an individual if statement.

#### Foreword

As mentioned in the comments on your question, run [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) to make sure you know where your performance problems are!

You mention your aversion to simply using boolean flags to make an if statement not run in your answer. This is fine, and it's what people normally do. This should not be an actual performance concern, and profiling will probably show your performance problems lie elsewhere. If they don't and this boolean flag check is genuinely your bottleneck - you have bigger problems, such as expecting too much from your JavaScript code, or that you didn't use the profiling tool correctly, or misinterpreted its results.

If you're trying to avoid running the body of an if statement, or its conditions, those are a bigger performance concern to you than the boolean flag check itself.

### For skipping a large group of if statements

Wrap your bunch of *if* statements in a condition.

```
if (runBunchOfIfStatements) {
    // all those if statements here
}
```

When you're past the point of wanting those if statements to run, set the `runBunchOfIfStatements` flag to false (of course, you should probably pick a more meaningful name than that).

That said, 8 or 9 if statements is a code length issue, and more than likely means nothing at all for performance concerns - unless those if statements happen to involve very intensive checks. If you're worried *just* because there's a lot of *if* checks, you're probably looking in the wrong place.

### For individual if statements

Say you have only *one* if statement you want to skip. You had this code in your answer:

```
} else if (x > 300 && !doneSomething2) {
  doSomething2();
  doneSomething2 = 1;
}
```

This is fine. You're just making a tiny check: see the foreword. Look elsewhere for your performance concern. It could be rewritten slightly to more closely follow convention (which I'm about to get to), but in this situation, the change will have negligible impact.

Let's take a situation where there *is* actually a performance concern here. Suppose that instead of checking `x > 300` you're doing something more intensive like `calculateSeveralSquareRoots()`. Generally, you *do* take this approach, but you rearrange it like this:

```
} else if (needCalculations && calculateSeveralSquareRoots() {
    // do stuff
    needCalculations = false;
}
```

The difference here is *the `needCalculations` flag comes first*, not second. JavaScript's comparison operators have [short circuit evaluation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that when evaluating `a && b`, if `a` is false, `b` never even gets checked - we already know the result will be false. If the flag comes first, that means `calculateSeveralSquareRoots()` never gets run, and you save time on the check.

If the flag came second, then you're potentially wasting a lot of time on that function for a condition that might almost always resolve to false anyway thanks to that flag.

So in your original, you could have the flag come *before* the `x > 300` evaluation, just to follow convention. But again... *if an if statement like this is a real and significant performance concern for you, then you have bigger issues.*

Comment: Grouping them is a good suggestion. I would want to remove them dynamically so they don't need to be processed using flags. So if an if statement was processed, you could write "remove this;" and it would remove that statement for good.

Comment: That breaks the behavior of the `else if` chain: `if (x > 200) { } else if (y) { if (x > 300) { y = true } } else if (x > 400) { }`

Comment: Hey pickypg, yes it would, unless js had something built into it that handled removing it. But given the responses, it doesn't look that way. But there are some great suggestions here.

Comment: @pikypg Then... don't do it like that? [You could do this](http://pastebin.com/c6Q9MrQn) for instance.

Comment: But that doesn't remove the middle one like in his question though. PS: if you're unfamiliar with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), then I'd give it a peek (not implying that you aren't, but I noticed the Pastebin link).

Comment: @pickypg Ah, I see what you're getting at. I figured he might've wanted to eliminate those 8 or 9 if statements in the same spot. Also thanks, I know of JSFiddle, though it probably would've been overkill for just writing that. 8)

Answer (score 2):

No. And the need for such would indicate poor design.

You should use a conditional expression to determine when which code segment should be run, as you mention. If you pass a certain threshold within your code after which you no longer want a condition to be executed in your loop, why not simply `break` the loop and have a new code block handling the `doSomethingElse` clause. If you're using `setInterval`, that's the point at which you would call `clearInterval`, and then trigger some new action if necessary. Anyway, running a single (or even a few) simple conditional statement doesn't add much overhead, and isn't likely to be the limiting factor in your optimization anyway.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion. Yes with the animation, I could do exactly that - clear the interval and set another one. I am going to do to do that. You really think it would be poor design? I think it would be tremendously useful if js had something built in like this.

Comment: Some of the calculations are checking if the count is greater than 300 and divisible by 7 and also checking a flag, for instance. By the time the animation is a minute in, it is checking through about 7 of these types of calculations, every 100ms. I know it is not much and the animation does run well, I just like to save any energy wherever I can so the animation is as fluid as possible. I also thought it would be elegant if js had something like this, so we didn't have to use flags. If it did, I wanted to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that I doubt this is a bottleneck in modern browsers that JIT the JavaScript (CPUs are very good at predictive branching) as shown because simple number comparison is not going to be expensive even in large iterations with smart predictions once it's compiled.

You can do this by injecting a different function:

```
checker: function(x) {
    if (x > 200) {
        doSomething1();
    }
    else if (x > 300) {
        doSomething2();
    }
    else if (y > 400) {
        doSomething3();
    }
}
```

Can be changed to

```
checker: function(x) {
    if (x > 200) {
        doSomething1();
    }
    else if (x > 300) {
        doSomething2();
        this.checker = smallerChecker;
    }
    else if (y > 400) {
        doSomething3();
    }
}

function smallerChecker(x) {
    if (x > 200) {
        doSomething1();
    }
    else if (y > 400) {
        doSomething3();
    }
}
```

Fundamentally, you simply need to make the behavior injectable, and then you change it however you see fit. Be-it by replacing the function doing the checking outright (the functional way) as I did above, or enabling an object to replace it (the OO way).

Answer (score 1):

Order them in order of likelihood (so if >400 is most common, check for that first, and if x<200 is next most common, check for that, etc.) The example code is in order of increasing boundaries.

Next, your code doesn't show it and you just imply it, this is in a loop. (And if it isn't a loop, then this isn't a perf issue of interest) You could try fancy loops like Duff's device.

And figuring out what code can be changed to use more native API's is going to make a magical difference, whereas code optimizations like this will likely make only a marginal difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be dynamic, you could always have a collection of conditions associated with actions and as soon as executed, these gets removed from the collection. However, I doubt it will lead to faster code execution, but you would have to create a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) test to know for sure.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/a2ZEj/1/**

```
function doSomethingA() {}
function doSomethingB() {}

var doOperation = (function doOperation() {
    var operations = [
        {
            check: function (someArg) {
                return someArg > 100;
            },
            exec: doSomethingA
        },
        {
            check: function (someArg) {
                return someArg > 100 && someArg < 200;
            },
            exec: doSomethingB
        }
    ];

    return function (someArg) {
        var i = 0,
            len = operations.length,
            item;

        for (; i < len; i++) {
            if ((item = operations[i]).check(someArg)) {
                item.exec();
                operations.splice(i, 1);
                console.log('executed ' + item.exec.name);
                return;
            }
        }
    };
})();

doOperation(101); //calls doSomethingA
doOperation(101); //calls doSomethingB
doOperation(101); //does nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method as below and create dynamic conditions

```
function buildCond(lhv1,rhv1,lhv2,rhv2) 
{
    var condition1,condition2;
    condition1 = condition2 = '';
    if(rhv1 !== -1){
        condition1 =  lhv1 + " == " + rhv1 + " && ";
    } 
    if(rhv2 !== -1){
        condition2 =  lhv2 + " == " + rhv2 + " && ";
    }
    return condition1 + condition2;
}

And then call this method with eval to execute

if(eval(buildCond(var1,value1,var2,value2)) === true){
    //do stuff
}
```